# Compile error: Multiple main functions in using service clients

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am implementing different services to get information hold by a database. I run a first simple service/client for the first query and it works. Now I am trying to do a second service/client. But that causes multiple 'main' definition. Isn't possible to hold different service/client with their own 'main' in the same package?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10767/compile-error:-multiple-main-functions-in-using-service-clients/) by [bnew](https://answers.ros.org/users/527/bnew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-29

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should only have one main and use both services from there.

If you want parallel execution you need to build two binaries or use threads.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3